# Express: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http

I am trying to learn Web APIs. I was writing a simple code that gets data from the server in the log after clicking a button, but I keep getting an error in the server side, which is "Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client".

My server side code:

```js
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();
projectData = [];

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.static("website"));

const port = 9013;
const server = app.listen(port, listening);

function listening  () {
    console.log("running localhost"+port);
}
let someData = {name:"name", num:"num"};
app.get ('/hello', function (req, res){
    res.send("Get request response");
    res.send(someData);
})
```

my client side code is:

```js
const generate = document.getElementById("generate");

generate.addEventListener("click", performAction);

function performAction (e) {
    getDemo();
}

const getDemo = async () => {
    const res = await fetch ("/hello");
    try {
    const data = await res.json();
    console.log(data);
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log("erroor");
    }
}
```

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That problem is something very basic. Here:

```
app.get ('/hello', function (req, res){
    res.send("Get request response");
    res.send(someData);
})
```

You cannot send a second response back. You already sent `Get request response` back to the client.

1 request = 1 response from server. Thats all.
Remove 1 line:

```
app.get ('/hello', function (req, res){
    res.send(someData);
})
```

Bonus: Just a hint, you should put your `fetch` inside the try / catch block not outside.

Comment: Thank you very much. I really appreciate it and thanks for the hint also.